# Creating new column in DataFrame with conditional rolling().mean()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am working on quite a large DataFrame and would like to speed things up. My data is in the following format:

| Name | Number |
| --- | --- |
| Condition 1 | 1 |
| Condition 1 | 2 |
| Condition 1 | 2.2 |
| Condition 1 | 2 |
| Condition 2 | 1 |
| Condition 2 | 1.1 |
| Condition 2 | 1.2 |
| Condition 2 | 1.3 |

Now I want to apply a rolling mean over the numbers, but without mixing different conditions. My expected outcome would be:

| Name | Number | Mean |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Condition 1 | 1 | nan |
| Condition 1 | 2 | 1.5 |
| Condition 1 | 2.2 | 2.1 |
| Condition 1 | 2 | 2.1 |
| Condition 2 | 1 | nan |
| Condition 2 | 1.1 | 1.05 |
| Condition 2 | 1.2 | 1.15 |
| Condition 2 | 1.3 | 1.25 |

What I am doing right now is to iterate over all conditions and save the calculated mean in a different Dataframe, like:

```
mean = {}
for con in data["Name"].drop_duplicates():
   mean[con] = data[data["Name" == con]].rolling(window=2).mean()
```

But this always takes several minutes, that's why I am looking for an alternative to create the column directly. I tried it with .apply but that doesn't work. At least not with what I tried so far.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by *Name* and then transform *Number* with the rolling mean:

```
df['Mean'] = df.groupby('Name')['Number'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(window=2).mean())
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
          Name  Number  Mean
0  Condition 1     1.0   NaN
1  Condition 1     2.0  1.50
2  Condition 1     2.2  2.10
3  Condition 1     2.0  2.10
4  Condition 2     1.0   NaN
5  Condition 2     1.1  1.05
6  Condition 2     1.2  1.15
7  Condition 2     1.3  1.25
```

Comment: Would this work without `transform`? `df['Mean'] = df.groupby('Name')['Number'].rolling(window=2).mean())`

Comment: @ScottBoston I'm getting error using that syntax, I'm using '1.1.4'

Comment: @DaniMesejo You're correct... `df['Mean'] = df.groupby('Name', as_index=True)['Number'].rolling(2).mean().to_numpy()`  Interesting `group_keys=False` isn't doing anything either.  I thought that worked at one point.

Comment: Dani Mesejo's Solution works like a charm and in seconds :D, Thank you very much, should've asked this earlier I guess. I tried the snippet without transform, but that does throw an error.

Comment: I see the problem, it creates a multiIndex. `df['Mean'] = df.groupby('Name')['Number'].rolling(window=2).mean().droplevel(0)` would be the solution then if we wanted to avoid transform for some reason.